# MySQL MIN/MAX Select based on different criteria in a single select statement

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

In mySQL, have a large table of history data and I am looking for an elegant way to be able to select the earliest/latest event types in a single select statement without grouping by Item and Event type and running multiple select statemements if possible as there are quite a few event types to consider. e.g from data like the below:

| ID | ITEM | EVENT | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Turn on | 10/09/2023 |
| 2 | a | Turn on | 11/09/2023 |
| 3 | a | Update | 11/09/2023 |
| 4 | a | Restart | 12/09/2023 |
| 5 | a | Turn on | 10/09/2023 |
| 6 | a | Turn on | 12/09/2023 |
| 7 | a | Restart | 10/09/2023 |
| 8 | a | Turn on | 11/09/2023 |
| 9 | a | Update | 11/09/2023 |
| 10 | a | Update | 12/09/2023 |

In order to return the first of each event type per item, I was hoping I could do something clever and neat along the lines of this if possible?

```
Select ID, 
MIN(Date WHERE event = 'Turn On')
MIN(Date WHERE event = 'Update')
MIN(Date WHERE event = 'Restart')
GROUP BY Item
```

If not the only way I can think of is to group by item and event, select the minumum for each event type and join these all together but was wondering if there is a simpler way?

Comment: as you want ro convert rows to columns you need always a group by

Comment: `MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'Turn On' THEN Date END)`

Comment: @nbk Not if the grouping is the entire table.

Comment: @Barmar he has more than one item, so group must be

Comment: As I read the question, they don't want per-item minimum, they want minimum across the entire table.

Comment: nbk is right I need to get the earlierst time per item. it looks like I do need to group by for each item/event combination

Answer (score 0):

Just as when pivoting, use a `CASE` expression inside the aggregate.

```
Select 
    MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'Turn On' THEN Date END) AS Turn_On
    MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'Update' THEN Date END) AS Update
    MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'Restart' THEN Date END) AS Restart
FROM yourTable
```

There's no point in selecting the `ID` column, since the ID is different for each minimum.

Answer (score 0):

you need always a `GROUP BY` if you want tp select , multiple items.

The solution Barmar provided will only function when sql_mode=only_full_group_by iws disabled

```
CREATE TABLE tab
    (`ID` int, `ITEM` varchar(1), `EVENT` varchar(7), `DATE` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO tab
    (`ID`, `ITEM`, `EVENT`, `DATE`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'Turn on', '2023-10-09 02:00:00'),
    (2, 'a', 'Turn on', '2023-11-09 01:00:00'),
    (3, 'a', 'Update', '2023-11-09 01:00:00'),
    (4, 'a', 'Restart', '2023-12-09 01:00:00'),
    (5, 'a', 'Turn on', '2023-10-09 02:00:00'),
    (6, 'a', 'Turn on', '2023-12-09 01:00:00'),
    (7, 'a', 'Restart', '2023-10-09 02:00:00'),
    (8, 'a', 'Turn on', '2023-11-09 01:00:00'),
    (9, 'a', 'Update', '2023-11-09 01:00:00'),
    (10, 'a', 'Update', '2023-12-09 01:00:00')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT 
     `ITEM`
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Turn on' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Turn on'
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Update' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Update'
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Restart' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Restart'

FROM tab 
GROUP BY ITEM
```

| ITEM | Turn on | Update | Restart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2023-10-09 02:00:00 | 2023-11-09 01:00:00 | 2023-10-09 02:00:00 |

```
SELECT 
     `ITEM`
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Turn on' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Turn on'
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Update' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Update'
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Restart' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Restart'

FROM tab 
  WHERE item = 'A'
GROUP BY ITEM
```

| ITEM | Turn on | Update | Restart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2023-10-09 02:00:00 | 2023-11-09 01:00:00 | 2023-10-09 02:00:00 |

```
SELECT 
     `ITEM`
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Turn on' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Turn on'
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Update' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Update'
  , MIN(CASE WHEN `EVENT` = 'Restart' THEN `DATE` END) as 'Restart'

FROM tab
```

> ```
> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.tab.ITEM'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ky-pbLVw)

Comment: You get an error because of `ITEM` in the `SELECT` list. Take that out and it will work without error.